# How to distribute the leased-line internet connection between 15 systems?

Tags: internet

We have a 2 MBPS dedicated leased line with 8 static Ip's, and we want to use it on 15 systems with one server. Service Provider offered the 1:1 Speed with 98.5% uptime.

I would like to know the system downloading speed and surfing speed on each system. there is no requirement of download in 14 systems except server.

Somebody suggest me the, speed would be divided by 8 like :- 2048 \ 8 \ 15 = 17 kbps per system .

I am totally confused the concept of downloading speed. Please suggest me .

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a total of 2Mbps available. Typically, a single machine with a 2Mbps line will download at about 215KB/s. When you have more than one machine using the line at the same time, the bandwidth will be divided somehow. It isn't necessarily going to be fair, but the total available will always be the raw line speed.

Comment: It's in the case of Dedicated Leased line ? if Yes' then why we are paying 250 USD per month to the service provider for dedicated line. we can use the Broadband it around 20 times cheaper. Please suggest ?

Comment: I'm not the person you should address that question to. You should address it to whoever decided to pay that much for the leased line. Presumably they thought it was worth the price. (Perhaps they needed static IP addresses and couldn't get them any other way? Perhaps they needed uptime guarantees or service response guarantees? Perhaps they were suckered by a slick salesman. Perhaps no cheaper provider permitted you to run a server. I don't know.)